# Prove that a linear combination that vanishes on a subset is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose I have $7$ homogeneous monomials in $4$ variables, namely  $$x^2,xy,y^2,xw,yz,z^2,w^2.$$

Suppose I know that any linear combination (with complex coefficients) of these vanishes when restricted to the set of common zeros of polynomials $wy-x^2,\ wz-xy,\ xz-y^2$ (in $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$ if you want). How do I show that this linear combination is trivial everywhere (on the whole $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the parametric curve $w = t^3, x=t^2, y=t, z=1$ is contained in the set of common zeros, and on that curve your monomials are respectively $t^4, t^3, t^2, t^5, t, 1, t^6$, which are obviously linearly independent.